# Magento Default Free Shipping not working with cart rule

Tags: magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping

I have Enabled free shipping from the admin.

[image]

Create shopping cart rule for apply freeshipping only if these condition are true.[image]

But it display for all.

I just want to free shipping only when cart price rule apply.

any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: What's are the shipping methods available for the customer without the free shipping?

Comment: Were you able to solve this Issue at hand? Appreciate your revert.